# How does one get Binary Blobs that are compatible with newer versions of Android, for older devices?

Tags: android, android-source

The hardware drivers for Nexus devices are provided on the android site. The android OS, is used on so many different devices by different manufacturers, that it was designed so that the many OS operates independent of the hardware (using the HAL).

So why isn't it simple for every nexus device to support future versions of Android, beyond the one that was last officially supported ? After building Marshmallow on Android a few times, it seems like the steps are:

1. Download source.
2. Add binary blobs for hardware (provided on android site)
3. Compile

For newer Android versions, at best I can imagine the missing step is that the old binary blobs may not be compatible with newer versions of Android API's. But the solution is just to use the blobs from newer devices (that have the same hardware) that do support a new version of Android.

Is that correct  (just get the blobs from a new device with the same hardware) ?

Answer (score 1):

Yep. You are right.

If there is no support for your device by the OEM, you can either shim the blobs with missing symbols (check logs for them) or update the blobs from latest device with same processor/hardware. Basically you need to update adreno, widevine and few more stuff and your device will be good to go.

Check https://github.com/LineageOS to check how to shim.

I hope it helps.